mysql breadcrumb with multiple joins
I would like to select all active categories and view it with a breadcrumb. In my database I have the following:



id_category
category_name
velleman_id
velleman_parent
prestashop_category
prestashop_category_2
prestashop_category_3
prestashop_category_4
deleted




1
Car & Bike
10





0


2
Bike
10.10
10




0


3
Car
10.15
10




0


4
Electric mat.
15





0


5
Wires
15.10
15




0


6
Connectors
15.15
15




0


7
Male
15.15.10
15.15




0


8
Round
15.15.10.10
15.15.10




0



The problem with my query is that it only shows categories where velleman_id contains 4 groups (like in id_category 8).
SELECT
    IFNULL(c4.id_category, IFNULL(c3.id_category, IFNULL(c2.id_category, IFNULL(c1.id_category, '')))) AS id_category,
    IFNULL(c1.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
    IFNULL(c2.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
    IFNULL(c3.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
    IFNULL(c4.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
    CONCAT(IFNULL(c1.category_name, ''), CONCAT(' > ', c2.category_name), CONCAT(' > ', c3.category_name), CONCAT(' > ', c4.category_name)) AS category_name,
    IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category, c1.prestashop_category))) AS prestashop_category,
    IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category_2, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category_2, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category_2, c1.prestashop_category_2))) AS prestashop_category_2,
    IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category_3, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category_3, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category_3, c1.prestashop_category_3))) AS prestashop_category_3,
    IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category_4, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category_4, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category_4, c1.prestashop_category_4))) AS prestashop_category_4,
    IFNULL(c4.deleted, IFNULL(c3.deleted, IFNULL(c2.deleted, c1.deleted))) AS deleted
FROM
    velleman_categories c1
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c2 ON
    c2.velleman_parent = c1.velleman_id
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c3 ON
    c3.velleman_parent = c2.velleman_id
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c4 ON
    c4.velleman_parent = c3.velleman_id
WHERE
    c1.velleman_parent = 0;

Tried to select with IFNULL and left join on the same table but with reference to previous joins.
When I select all active rows, I have 523 rows:
SELECT * FROM velleman_categories WHERE deleted = 0;

And with the query above I have 423 rows.
This is what I like to get:



id_category
velleman_id
velleman_id
velleman_id
velleman_id
category_name
prestashop_category
prestashop_category_2
prestashop_category_3
prestashop_category_4




4
15
(empty or null)
(empty or null)
(empty or null)
Electric mat.
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)


8
15
15.15
15.15.10
15.15.10.10
Electric mat. > Connectors > Male > Round
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)



I think the problem is with the JOIN and that some parents have no values or maybe a root category.

Please add your desired outcome based on the published sample data.

Vellman_id appears in the query but not in the data...please make the data, query and question text consistent

@P.Salmon I updated the question with the desired results!

WHERE    c1.velleman_parent = 0;, but I do see some, of them, having values like 15.15.10.  what data type is that?  Please add the DDL for the table velleman_categories.

You need to modify the condition in your JOIN, add the base table (c), and change the CONCAT for the category_name.
Here is the working query:
SELECT
IFNULL(c4.id_category, IFNULL(c3.id_category, IFNULL(c2.id_category, IFNULL(c1.id_category, '')))) AS id_category,
IFNULL(c1.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
IFNULL(c2.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
IFNULL(c3.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
IFNULL(c4.velleman_id, '') AS velleman_id,
CONCAT_WS(' > ', c1.category_name, c2.category_name, c3.category_name, c4.category_name) AS category_name,
IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category, c1.prestashop_category))) AS prestashop_category,
IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category_2, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category_2, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category_2, c1.prestashop_category_2))) AS prestashop_category_2,
IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category_3, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category_3, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category_3, c1.prestashop_category_3))) AS prestashop_category_3,
IFNULL(c4.prestashop_category_4, IFNULL(c3.prestashop_category_4, IFNULL(c2.prestashop_category_4, c1.prestashop_category_4))) AS prestashop_category_4,
IFNULL(c4.deleted, IFNULL(c3.deleted, IFNULL(c2.deleted, c1.deleted))) AS deleted
FROM velleman_categories c
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c1 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.velleman_id, '.', 1) = c1.velleman_id
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c2 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.velleman_id, '.', 2) = c2.velleman_id AND LENGTH(c.velleman_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(c.velleman_id, '.', '')) > 0
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c3 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.velleman_id, '.', 3) = c3.velleman_id AND LENGTH(c.velleman_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(c.velleman_id, '.', '')) > 1
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c4 ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.velleman_id, '.', 4) = c4.velleman_id AND LENGTH(c.velleman_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(c.velleman_id, '.', '')) > 2

Result:
here

You are missing the category_name on id_category is 4 (as asked in the question)

Hi @Luuk I modified your CONCAT for category_name and it's working now as expected. Check my edits.

Indeed CONCAT_WS is a better option than what I did.  But I have never used it, and that's why I did not use it..

Understood @Luuk.  I hope the answer solved the problem.

One tip:  take a look at https://dbfiddle.uk/  because it is so much better than a screen shot....

Example It's partial dutch but you'll see how it looks now.

I am using the fact that CONCAT(null,'text') returns null, so I need not use IFNULL:
SELECT 
   c1.id_category,
   c1.velleman_id,
   c2.velleman_id as id_2,
   c3.velleman_id as id_3,
   c4.velleman_id as id_4,
   CONCAT(COALESCE(CONCAT(c4.category_name,' > '),''),
          COALESCE(CONCAT(c3.category_name, ' > '),''), 
          COALESCE(CONCAT(c2.category_name, ' > ')), 
          c1.category_name)  as breadcrumb
FROM velleman_categories c1
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c2 ON c2.velleman_id  = c1.velleman_parent
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c3 ON c3.velleman_id  = c2.velleman_parent
LEFT JOIN velleman_categories c4 ON c4.velleman_id  = c3.velleman_parent
; 

output:



id_category
velleman_id
id_2
id_3
id_4
breadcrumb




1
10






2
10.10
10


Car & Bike > Bike


3
10.15
10


Car & Bike > Car


4
15






5
15.10
15


Electric mat. > Wires


6
15.15
15


Electric mat. > Connectors


7
15.15.10
15.15
15

Electric mat. > Connectors > Male


8
15.15.10.10
15.15.10
15.15
15
Electric mat. > Connectors > Male > Round



see: DBFIDDLE

A recursve cte can get you most of the way insofar as you can establish breadcrumbs for category,ids and level.
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (id, name, ids,path,level) AS
(
  SELECT velleman_id, category_name, cast(velleman_id as char(200)),cast(category_name  as char(200)),1
    FROM velleman_categories
    WHERE velleman_parent =''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT velleman_id, category_name, concat(cte.ids,'|', vc.velleman_id),
         CONCAT(cte.path, ',', vc.category_name),cte.level +1
  FROM   cte 
  JOIN velleman_categories vc ON cte.id = vc.velleman_parent
  
)
select * from cte;

it's then possible to establish if a shorter breadcrumb exists in a longer breadcrumb and then you know the top and bottom of a chain
WITH RECURSIVE CTE (id, name, ids,path,level) AS
(
  SELECT velleman_id, category_name, cast(velleman_id as char(200)),cast(category_name  as char(200)),1
    FROM velleman_categories
    WHERE velleman_parent =''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT velleman_id, category_name, concat(cte.ids,'|', vc.velleman_id),
         CONCAT(cte.path, ',', vc.category_name),cte.level +1
  FROM   cte 
  JOIN velleman_categories vc ON cte.id = vc.velleman_parent
  
)
select *
from
(
SELECT distinct cte.* ,substring_index(cte1.ids,'|',cte.level) appearslater
FROM cte 
left join cte cte1  on cte1.level = cte.level + 1 and substring_index(cte1.ids,'|',cte.level) = cte.ids
) s
where s.level = 1 or appearslater is null
;

https://dbfiddle.uk/ni3V5yx_
